# What is a "jump response" of a filter?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, finite-impulse-response, step-response

I know how to determine if a filter is FIR or IIR, but I don't understand the question. What is a "jump response"?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad translation of *step response*, i.e., the filter's response to a unit step $u[n]$ at the input. Note that the step response is the convolution of the unit step with the filter's impulse response:

$$s[n]=\big(u\star h\big)[n]=\sum_{k=0}^nh[k],\qquad n\ge 0\tag{1}$$

where I've assumed causality, i.e., $h[n]=0$ for $n<0$.

From the given step response and Eq. $(1)$ it should be easy to derive the impulse response $h[n]$. You can also immediately draw a conclusion about its length. Then, by considering the symmetry of $h[n]$, I'm sure you know how to derive the group delay of the filter.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Knowing it is a step response, it would be very easy to continue on! Thank you very much